# How do you convert to lambda syntax?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Part of a question I'm trying to understand involves this:

```
twice (twice) f x , where twice == lambda f x . f (f x)
```

I'm trying to understand how to make that substitution, and what it means.

My understanding is that (lambda x y . x + y) 2 3 == 2 + 3 == 5. I don't understand what twice (twice) means, or f ( f x ).

Comment: See Currying(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).  Twice is a function that takes in a function (f) and returns a function that takes in an argument (x) and returns the result of applying f to the result of applying f to x.

Comment: (lambda x y . x + y) is a function that takes in a number (call it x) and returns a [function that takes in a number (call it y) and returns x + y].  When you apply (lambda x y . x + y) to 2, you get a function that adds 2 to numbers.  When you apply _that_ function to 3, you get 5.

Comment: Hmm. So Lfx. f ( f x )....if f is being applied to f of x, why isn't x in parentheses as well? Why not Lfx. f ( f (x) ) )?

Comment: In the syntax you are using, function application is just a space.  This is rather unlike C, where function application requires parentheses.  You can get away with that in the lambda calculus because all functions have only one argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways of looking at this.

#### Mechanical application of beta-reduction

You can solve this mechanically just by expanding any subterm of the form `twice` F X - with this term you will eventually eliminate all the occurences of twice, although you need to take care that you really understand the syntax tree of the lambda calculus to avoid mistakes.

`twice` takes two arguments, so your expression `twice (twice) f x` is the redex `twice (twice) f` applied to `x`. (A redex is a subterm that you can reduce independently of the rest of the term).

Expand the definition of `twice` in the redex: `twice (twice) f x -> twice (twice f)`.

Substitute this into the original term to get `twice (twice f) x`, which is another redex we can expand `twice` in to get `twice f (twice f x)` (take care with the brackets in this step).

We have two `twice` redexes we can expand here, expanding the one inside the brackets is slightly simpler, giving `twice f (f (f x))`, which can again be expanded to give `f (f (f (f x)))`.

#### Semantics of twice via abstraction

You can see what's going on at a more intuitive level by appealing to a higher-order combinator, the "○" infix combinator for function composition:

```
f ○ g = lambda x. f (g x)
```

It's easy to verify that `twice f x` and `(f ○ f) x` both expand to the same normal form, i.e., `f (f x),` so by extensionality, we have

```
twice f = f ○ f
```

Using this, we can expand very straightforwardly, first eliminating `twice` in favour of the composition combinator:

```
twice (twice) f x
= (twice ○ twice)  f x
= (twice (twice f)) x         /* expand out '○' */
= (twice (f ○ f)) x
= ((f ○ f) ○ (f ○ f)) x
```

and then expanding out '○':

```
= (f ○ f) ((f ○ f) x)
= (f ○ f) (f (f x))
= (f (f (f (f x))))
```

That's more expansion steps, because we first expand to terms containing the '○' operator, and then expand these operators out, but the steps are simpler, more intuitive ones, where you are less likely to misunderstand what you are doing.  The '○' is widely used, standard operator in Haskell and is well worth getting used to.